# Clickhouse subquery

Tags: python-3.x, clickhouse

I'm working on deletions from ClickHouse, but I've encountered a problem where nothing gets deleted when using a subquery.

This query is not working:

```
f"""
 DELETE FROM signals WHERE signal_id = {signal_id} AND order IN  (
     SELECT order AS order FROM signals
     WHERE signal_id = {signal_id}
     ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT {limit}
 )
 """
```

This is working:

```
ids_to_delete = client.execute(f" SELECT order as order FROM signals WHERE signal_id = {signal_id} ORDER BY order ASC LIMIT {limit};")
ids_to_delete = [i[0] for i in ids_to_delete]
ids_string = ', '.join(map(str, ids_to_delete))
client.execute(f"DELETE FROM signals WHERE signal_id = {signal_id} AND order IN ({ids_string})")
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: ClickHouse version?

Comment: @gingerwizard 22.10-alpine